# /current/ date range contextual filter

Tags: views

I have a view `/widgets` with a couple of optional contextual filters of type "Has taxonomy term converted to ID", so the url can look like this:

- `/widgets/blue`
- `/widgets/big`
- `/widgets/small/green`

And so on.

But there should also be a "current" contextual filter on the date field defined as such:

[image]

Currently, we used exposed date filters as such:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But for "current" widgets, my urls look like this:

`/widgets/blue/small?field_date_value_op=<%3D&field_date_value%5Bvalue%5D%5Bdate%5D=2013-05-17&field_date_value2_op=>%3D&field_date_value2%5Bvalue%5D%5Bdate%5D=2013-05-17`

How to make:

- `/widgets/blue/small/current` do a filtering like `field_date_value<=today && field_date_value2>=today` ?
- `/widgets/past` do a filtering like `field_date_value2<today`
- `/widgets/future` to `field_date_value>today`

Comment: Would help if you could describe your filter. What field type is it (that we can guess), what are default values & operators etc. What's your Drupal and Views major versions? "Today" is generally supported, but not for ranges. Well, I guess it is possible to make it ?from=today&to=today for range, but that'a about that.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'm trying to have `start_date<=today && end_date>=today` in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Views Contextual Range Filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter)

> Views Contextual Range Filter is a simple plugin for Views that adds
>   the option to contextually filter not just by a single value, but also
>   by range.
>
> Numeric, alphabetical and list ranges are all supported. Node ids,
>   user ids and even taxonomy term ids are all special cases of numbers
>   so will work also. Range-filtering on dates is also supported. For
>   this you may use either the absolute date format as dictated by Views,
>   YYYYMMDD, or the relative format, which supports natural language
>   phrases like six months ago, today noon and even first Tuesday of
>   November

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create 3 sub-pages with normal filters, /widgets/all /widgets/past /widgets/current and /widgets/future.